# adding array.each to variable gives no method for "+" for nil (!?) method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, methods, each, null

I'm working on my studies project and I have a problem with taking some data from an array to the variable.

```
    m_id = params[:m_id]    #from the search form

    headers  = {:accept => "application/json"}
    response = RestClient.get "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/#{m_id}?api_key=8f8bdc43aaf51d09127c3eb023007a53", headers     
    parsed_json = JSON.parse(response)

    movie_act = Movie.new
    parsed_json["production_countries"].each { |e| movie_act.country += e["name"] }
```

And the for the code

```
    movie_act.country = parsed_json["production_countries"][0]["name"].to_s
```

It is all right (despite the fact that it gives only one country, first one - I need all coutries).

The error I get is:

```
 NoMethodError in MoviesController#create

 undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
 Rails.root: C:/Users/Asus/Moje dokumenty/GitHub/interfejs

 Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
 app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:94:in `block in create'
 app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:93:in `each'
 app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:93:in `create'
```

What's the problem? Please help!

Comment: Have you tried with `.each { |e| movie_act.country << e["name"] }` ? This implies that `movie_act.country` is an array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `+=` on `movie_act.country`, but `movie_act.country` is returning `nil`.

What type of object is `movie_act.country` supposed to be? An `Array`? A `String`? In either case, you can avoid this error by initializing it with an empty value before your `.each` loop, e.g. (assuming you're expecting it to be an `Array`),

```
movie_act = Movie.new(:country => [])
parsed_json["production_countries"].each { |e| movie_act.country += e["name"] }
```